# Sorl-thumbnail repo asking for password

Tags: django, mercurial, thumbnails, pip, sorl-thumbnail

Im trying to clone hg+https://sorl-thumbnail.googlecode.com/hg/#egg=sorl-thumbnail in order to use it with my satchmo store.

I have the link on a requirements file, but is asking me for a password, I tought it was a google password but it does not work for me.

What username/password is looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page has been shut down.

Get it from github or these other links listed here:
https://github.com/sorl/sorl-thumbnail/wiki

Answer (score 0):

`pip install sorl-thumbnail` works at this time.